# Match words between some characters with any nesting level (regex)

Tags: javascript, regex

Let's imagine I have some string :

```
Hello, I'm this (not (usual)) string
```

I want to match the words `not` and `usual`. It can be any nesting level, `(not (usual(anything)))`, etc. I've done this solution `\((.*?)\)`, but it only matches the first level `(not (usual)`. The response should be `["not", "usual", "anything"]`

Comment: Is something like `'A string with (two (sets)) of (nested(brackets))'` possible input?

Comment: @Nick , yes, possible input

Answer (score 1):

You may use a trick to get all text from the innermost parentheses withing a `replace` method with the `/\(([^()]*)\)/g` regex where the second argument is a callback method, where you can add found matches to an array. You should remove those matches, and run the replacements a while loop until no replacement is made:

```js
var input = "Hello, I'm this (not (usual(anything))) string",
    output = input,
    results = [];
while (output != (output = output.replace(/\(([^()]*)\)/g, function(a,b) { if (b) results.push(b); return ""; } ))); 
console.log(results);
```

I added a condition to `if (b) results.push(b);` to avoid returning empty matches (if the string contains `()`). You may remove this and just use `results.push(b)` if you want to get empty matches, too.